# sympy py2exe creates RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded

Tags: python, python-2.7, runtime-error, py2exe, sympy

I have reinstalled python2.7 on windows XP.
I installed :

- sympy 0.7.5 using http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/
- py2exe 0.6.9 using [SourceForge py2exe0.6.9 py2.7](http://sourceforge.net/projects/py2exe/files/py2exe/0.6.9/)

The following code works, file hello.py:

> ```
> import sympy
> if __name__ == '__main__':
>     print "hello world of sympy"
> ```

1. The setup.py file is simple

> ```
> from distutils.core import setup
> import py2exe
> setup(console=['hello.py'])
> ```

1. The `python py2exe hello.py` gives me the following error:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "setup.py", line 4, in <module>
>     setup(console=['hello.py'])
>   File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\core.py", line 152, in setup
>     dist.run_commands()
>   File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
>     self.run_command(cmd)
>   File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 972, in run_command
>     cmd_obj.run()
>   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\py2exe\build_exe.py", line 243, in run
>     self._run()
>   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\py2exe\build_exe.py", line 296, in _run
>     self.find_needed_modules(mf, required_files, required_modules)
>   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\py2exe\build_exe.py", line 1277, in find_needed_modules
>     mf.run_script(path)
>   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 713, in run_script
>     Base.run_script(self, pathname)
>   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 124, in run_script
>     self.load_module('__main__', fp, pathname, stuff)
>   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 730, in load_module
>     r = Base.load_module(self, fqname, fp, pathname, (suffix, mode, typ))
>   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 314, in load_module
>     self.scan_code(co, m)
>   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 423, in scan_code
>     self._safe_import_hook(name, m, fromlist, level=level)
>   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 332, in _safe_import_hook
>     self.import_hook(name, caller, level=level)
>   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 719, in import_hook
>     return Base.import_hook(self,name,caller,fromlist,level)
>   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 136, in import_hook
>     q, tail = self.find_head_package(parent, name)
>   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 192, in find_head_package
>     q = self.import_module(head, qname, parent)
>   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 724, in import_module
>     r = Base.import_module(self,partnam,fqname,parent)
>   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 284, in import_module
>     m = self.load_module(fqname, fp, pathname, stuff)
> ```

.... etc. and the message ends with:

```
    r = Base.load_module(self, fqname, fp, pathname, (suffix, mode, typ))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 314, in load_module
    self.scan_code(co, m)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 423, in scan_code
    self._safe_import_hook(name, m, fromlist, level=level)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 332, in _safe_import_hook
    self.import_hook(name, caller, level=level)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 719, in import_hook
    return Base.import_hook(self,name,caller,fromlist,level)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 137, in import_hook
    m = self.load_tail(q, tail)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 214, in load_tail
    m = self.import_module(head, mname, m)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 724, in import_module
    r = Base.import_module(self,partnam,fqname,parent)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 284, in import_module
    m = self.load_module(fqname, fp, pathname, stuff)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 730, in load_module
    r = Base.load_module(self, fqname, fp, pathname, (suffix, mode, typ))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 293, in load_module
    self.msgin(2, "load_module", fqname, fp and "fp", pathname)
```

**RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded**

So, I can't create exe with the simple program. Does someone know how to proceed next ? Is there something to check ?

Comment: This is most likely caused by a circular import within sympy confusing py2exe's module finder. https://github.com/sympy/sympy/commit/aeac550319464c2e7ce534c4ccb91ad3391d804f appears to be a fix for such an issue, although I have not tested this.